# JavaFX primaryStage binding with TextField

Tags: javafx

In JavaFx I'm currently trying to change the height of 
`primaryStage` via binding.

```
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.setHeight(400.0);
     primaryStage.widthProperty().bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty());
```

It's just a homework problem, not meaningful. 
Unfortunately `primaryStage` is `readOnlyDoubleProperty`. May I change this settings to gain write-permissions?

I know, there is the possibility to change the window size via `EventHandler`, but I would like to change the window size on the fly through the `TextField` with bindings.
So any newly entered number enlarges the window.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no "settings" to change. The API only exposes that property, and related properties, as read-only because the values can be changed from outside the application and thus unidirectional bindings must be impossible. Also, binding the width of a window to the text of a text field doesn't make sense; what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Our teacher wants us to built a Pane with a TextField in it. When you start typing numbers, the whole window should enlarge. But not with an Handler, but directly while typing using a binding. I did not find any hints for this problem. It´s nothing meaningful, just homework. Mabye his intention has been  keeping us working on JavaFX with this stuff! But thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly, what I found out.

Comment: There is no "gaining write permission" on properties that do not implement this, especially not using a `StringProperty`. This is done on purpose, since the window can e.g. be resized by the user which would either leave the property in an inconsistent state or make the window non-resizeable which is controlled by another property. There are setters though... Just add a listener to the property and use the setter....

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible and I hope there is a better way and **no one should ever use this code ever** but this is what I managed to make work

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        //Allows for only numeric input
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
            if (change.getText().matches("[0-9]*"))
                return change;
            else
                return null;
        }));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(textField));
        primaryStage.setHeight(200.0);

        //Allows Program to start without error
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(200);

        //Binds min and max to ensure stage width change due to only 1 possible size
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.maxWidthProperty());

        //Bind textfield to width
        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(primaryStage.maxWidthProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) not suitable for allowing only numeric input for the `TextField` ?